# Geometric intuition behind simple identities of derivatives of polar coordinates

Tags: partial-derivative, intuition, polar-coordinates, jacobian

Consider planar coordinates, given (say in the first quadrant to avoid any range issues) by

$$\left\lbrace \begin{matrix}x=r\cos\theta\\y=r\sin\theta\\\end{matrix}\right.\qquad\text{and}\qquad\left\lbrace \begin{matrix}r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\\\theta=\arctan \frac yx\ \ \\\end{matrix}\right.$$

One straightforwardly computes that ${\partial x\over\partial r}=\cos\theta$
and ${\partial y\over\partial r}=\sin\theta$. It turns out that computing the derivatives the other way around yields the same results:
$${\partial r\over\partial x}={\partial \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\over\partial x}=\frac12\frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} =\cos\theta\ \ \left(={\partial x\over\partial r}\right)$$
and similarly ${\partial r\over\partial y}={\partial y\over\partial r}$.

Apart from direct computation, one could also argue that the inverse of the jacobian matrix $\left(\matrix{\cos\theta&-r\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&r\cos\theta\\}\right)$ is $\left(\matrix{\cos\theta&\sin\theta\\-\frac{\sin\theta}{r}&\frac{\cos\theta}{r}\\}\right)$ where one can see that the entries $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$ appear twice.

**Is there yet a deeper, possibly geometrical, explanation for the identities $\displaystyle{\partial x\over\partial r}={\partial r\over\partial x}$
and $\displaystyle{\partial y\over\partial r}={\partial r\over\partial y}$?**

**To which extent can one regard this as an intrinsic natural definition of $\cos$ and $\sin$?**

Comment: Why isn't $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{\cos\theta}?$

Comment: @saulspatz Because a partial derivative is not a fraction even though the notation looks like it. Compute it, you will see (use the chain rule).

Comment: I did, starting from $r=x/\cos\theta$

Comment: @saulspatz I edited to clarify. Your computation is wrong because you treat $\theta$ as being independent from $x$ which it is not. That is, ${\partial \theta\over\partial x}\neq 0$.

Comment: Partial derivative notation is ambiguous. The calculation is "wrong" because you and @saulspatz assign different meanings to the notation.

Comment: $\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}$ assumes $\theta$ fixed.  $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}$ assumes $y$ fixed.  They are just different, not the inverses of each other.

Comment: @herbsteinberg They are different in nature, true, but their numerical value at any given point is the same, which is the reason for my question.

Comment: @ Arnaud Mortier Sketch two pictures of what is happening around a particular point on the circumference of a circle, one showing a small change in r with $\theta$ fixed and the with a small change in x with y fixed, you will see small right triangles.   In the first picture $\Delta r$ will be the hypotenuse and $\Delta x$ the adjacent leg where $\theta$ is the angle.  In the second picture $\Delta x$ is the hypotenuse while $\Delta r$ is the opposite leg while $\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta$ is the angle.  I guess this is what shows up in the Jacobian matrix transformation.